# macro to open new workbook and close current if higher version is available in share drive

Tags: vba, excel

My team use a workbook from shared drive which is in read only mode for them for updtaes.
workbok name has last 3 digits as version of workbook i.e " Helpdesk 1.1"
I am looking for a code whcih will find in share drive if any higher version is available in share drive from where this workbook was open and if macro finds any workbook with name Helpdesk 1.2 it should give a msg box saying " A higher Version is Available, Do you want to open that".
If we say yes it should close current workbook and open new version i.e Helpdesk 1.2.
I tried a lot to write such code however nothing is working.
Can anyone help me on this please.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. However for future references you will need to show what you have tried. You are not always going to find people to write a code for you

```
   Sub CheckVersion() 'This will only work if we your file name format is exactly as you had decribed "Helpdesk x.x"
        Dim sharedFolder As String, myFile As String
        sharedFolder = "\\mySharedDrivePath\Documents" 'Change to whatever is your case
        myFile = Dir(sharedFolder & "\*.xlsx")
        Dim rex As New RegExp
        rex.Pattern = "Helpdesk (\d+\.\d+)"
        Do While myFile <> ""
            If CDbl(rex.Execute(ThisWorkbook.Name)(0).SubMatches(0)) < CDbl(rex.Execute(myFile)(0).SubMatches(0)) Then
                msg1 = MsgBox("Newer Version found " & rex.Execute(myFile)(0).SubMatches(0), vbYesNo, "Open newer version?")
                If msg1 = vbYes Then
                    Workbooks.Open (myFile)
                    ThisWorkbook.Close
                End If
            End If
            myFile = Dir
        Loop
    End Sub
```